# How to update all post at once?

Tags: posts, slug

Is there a way to update all post at once?

The issue is, when i migrated content from another CMS, some of the permalinks are working fine and some of them are not, when i updated the posts all links are working fine.

I have tried some methods to perform this requirement, but it doesn't helped.

Comment: What exactly do you want to update?  A simple WP_Query loop would accomplish your goal.  Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: There is multiple posts with busted links in the database, when i am clicking on the permalink it returns 404 and when i republish the post the permalink is working well. There is 3000 posts in the database so i need to republish all those posts at once.

Comment: Ok, and what's busted?  Have you changed something?  Migrated to a new url?  Why are those links broken?

Comment: Entire content is migrated from another CMS. So the issue is there only when clicking on some permalinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all,

The issue is resolved by removing special characters from wp_posts -> post_name.

Now all permalinks are working fine.

Comment: Very glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Post Bulk Update
Description: Updates certain fields of my posts at once. On Activation. Awesome
Author: Me. I did it
*/
add_action('init','post_bulk_update');

function post_bulk_update(){
 $posts_to_update = new WP_Query('cat=x&showposts=1000');
while($posts_to_update ->have_posts()) : $posts_to_update ->the_post();
$postUpdateArray = array();
$postUpdateArray ['ID'] = $post->ID;//Don't remove this. The ID is mandatory
$postUpdateArray ['post_title'] = 'Post Prefix: '.$post->post_title;
     wp_update_post( $postUpdateArray );
endwhile;

}
```

For more reference see [this](http://kakoma.ug/code/2013/09/wordpress-tutorial-update-posts-category/).

Comment: Hey @Rohit Pande the original question didn't provide enough information to actually answer the question. Imo, it would have been beneficial to request clarification to pin point exactly what the problem was.